# Fast vectorized merge of list of data.frames by row

Tags: r, performance, list, merge, dataframe

Most of the questions about merging data.frame in lists on SO don't quite relate to what I'm trying to get across here, but feel free to prove me wrong.

I have a list of data.frames. I would like to "rbind" rows into another data.frame by row. In essence, all first rows form one data.frame, second rows second data.frame and so on.
Result would be a list of the same length as the number of rows in my original data.frame(s). So far, the data.frames are identical in dimensions.

Here's some data to play around with.

```
sample.list <- list(data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10), y = sample(1:100, 10), capt = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
        data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10), y = sample(1:100, 10), capt = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
        data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10), y = sample(1:100, 10), capt = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
        data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10), y = sample(1:100, 10), capt = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
        data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10), y = sample(1:100, 10), capt = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
        data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10), y = sample(1:100, 10), capt = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)),
        data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10), y = sample(1:100, 10), capt = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)))
```

Here's what I've come up with with the good ol' for loop.

```
#solution 1
my.list <- vector("list", nrow(sample.list[[1]]))
for (i in 1:nrow(sample.list[[1]])) {
    for (j in 1:length(sample.list)) {
        my.list[[i]] <- rbind(my.list[[i]], sample.list[[j]][i, ])
    }
}

#solution 2 (so far my favorite)
sample.list2 <- do.call("rbind", sample.list)
my.list2 <- vector("list", nrow(sample.list[[1]]))

for (i in 1:nrow(sample.list[[1]])) {
    my.list2[[i]] <- sample.list2[seq(from = i, to = nrow(sample.list2), by = nrow(sample.list[[1]])), ]
}
```

Can this be improved using vectorization without much brainhurt? Correct answer will contain a snippet of code, of course. "Yes" as an answer doesn't count.

*EDIT*

```
#solution 3 (a variant of solution 2 above)
ind <- rep(1:nrow(sample.list[[1]]), times = length(sample.list))
my.list3 <- split(x = sample.list2, f = ind)
```

*BENCHMARKING*

I've made my list larger with more rows per data.frame. I've benchmarked the results which are as follows:

```
#solution 1
system.time(for (i in 1:nrow(sample.list[[1]])) {
    for (j in 1:length(sample.list)) {
        my.list[[i]] <- rbind(my.list[[i]], sample.list[[j]][i, ])
    }
})
   user  system elapsed 
 80.989   0.004  81.210 

# solution 2
system.time(for (i in 1:nrow(sample.list[[1]])) {
    my.list2[[i]] <- sample.list2[seq(from = i, to = nrow(sample.list2), by = nrow(sample.list[[1]])), ]
})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.957   0.160   1.126 

# solution 3
system.time(split(x = sample.list2, f = ind))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.104   0.204   1.332 

# solution Gabor
system.time(lapply(1:nr, bind.ith.rows))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.484   0.000   0.485 

# solution ncray
system.time(alply(do.call("cbind",sample.list), 1,
                .fun=matrix, ncol=ncol(sample.list[[1]]), byrow=TRUE,
                dimnames=list(1:length(sample.list),names(sample.list[[1]]))))
   user  system elapsed 
 11.296   0.016  11.365
```

Comment: Why o why did I forget about split? Very nice solution!

Comment: Very nice demonstration. This kind of situation was one of the few where I still tend to use for loops, but pretty clear why that's a bad idea :)

Comment: @jonw, I guess it depends on what you're after. If you have medium or smallish data sets, loops are fine.

Comment: How about this merged.list = do.call('rbind', sample.list)

Comment: Unfortunately this just merges the list into one big data.frame. This is the intermediate step I use in my solution #2.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Misread the question

Comment: @DWin Hi. I don't follow your new bounty, what's it for?

Comment: I had read that it was possible to award bounties even if the question was already answered. So I decided to go looking for good answers. This one is posing a bit of a problem for me however, because mnel's DT solution appears better than the accepted solution that I originally planned to award.

Comment: @DWin Interesting, nice idea. I didn't realise somebody other than the asker could award bounty, either.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
bind.ith.rows <- function(i) do.call(rbind, lapply(sample.list, "[", i, TRUE))
nr <- nrow(sample.list[[1]])
lapply(1:nr, bind.ith.rows)
```

Comment: To what argument does TRUE correspond to?

Comment: It gives `sample.list[i, TRUE]` which is the same as `sample.list[i, ]`.  If we left out `TRUE` we would have `sample.list[i]` which would pick out a column rather than the desired result which is to pick out a row.

Comment: This is the best bit of R I've ever seen

Answer (score 40):

A couple of solutions that will make this quicker using `data.table`

**EDIT** - with larger dataset showing  `data.table` awesomeness even more.

```
# here are some sample data 
sample.list <- replicate(10000, data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 10), 
  y = sample(1:100, 10), capt = sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)), simplify = F)
```

Gabor's fast solution:

```
# Solution Gabor
bind.ith.rows <- function(i) do.call(rbind, lapply(sample.list, "[", i, TRUE))
nr <- nrow(sample.list[[1]])
system.time(rowbound <- lapply(1:nr, bind.ith.rows))

##    user  system elapsed 
##   25.87    0.01   25.92
```

The data.table function `rbindlist` will make this *even* quicker even when working with data.frames)

```
library(data.table)
fastbind.ith.rows <- function(i) rbindlist(lapply(sample.list, "[", i, TRUE))
system.time(fastbound <- lapply(1:nr, fastbind.ith.rows))

##    user  system elapsed 
##   13.89    0.00   13.89
```

### A `data.table` solution

Here is a solution that uses data.tables - it is `split` solution on steroids.

```
# data.table solution
system.time({
    # change each element of sample.list to a data.table (and data.frame) this
    # is done instaneously by reference
    invisible(lapply(sample.list, setattr, name = "class", 
               value = c("data.table",  "data.frame")))
    # combine into a big data set
    bigdata <- rbindlist(sample.list)
    # add a row index column (by refere3nce)
    index <- as.character(seq_len(nr))
    bigdata[, `:=`(rowid, index)]
    # set the key for binary searches
    setkey(bigdata, rowid)
    # split on this -
    dt_list <- lapply(index, function(i, j, x) x[i = J(i)], x = bigdata)
    # if you want to drop the `row id` column
    invisible(lapply(dt_list, function(x) set(x, j = "rowid", value = NULL)))
    # if you really don't want them to be data.tables run this line
    # invisible(lapply(dt_list, setattr,name = 'class', value =
    # c('data.frame')))
})
################################
##    user  system elapsed    ##
##    0.08    0.00    0.08    ##
################################
```

How awesome is `data.table`!

## Caveat user with `rbindlist`

`rbindlist` is fast because it does not perform the checking that `do.call(rbind,....)` will. For example it assumes that any factor columns have the same levels as in the first element of the list.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my attempt with plyr, but I like G. Grothendieck's approach:

```
library(plyr)
alply(do.call("cbind",sample.list), 1, .fun=matrix,
        ncol=ncol(sample.list[[1]]), byrow=TRUE,
        dimnames=list(1:length(sample.list),
        names(sample.list[[1]])
      ))
```

Comment: can you provide a dplyr solution.

Answer (score 1):

addind `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(sample.list)
```