# How can I prevent rbind() from geting really slow as dataframe grows larger?

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, append, rbind

I have a dataframe with only 1 row. To this I start to add rows by using rbind

```
df #mydataframe with only one row
for (i in 1:20000)
{
    df<- rbind(df, newrow)

}
```

this gets very slow as i grows. Why is that? and how can I make this type of code faster?

Comment: Because you are in the [second circle of hell](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: @joran, that's an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are in the [2nd circle of hell](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), namely failing to pre-allocate data structures.

Growing objects in this fashion is a Very Very Bad Thing in R. Either pre-allocate and insert:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(NA,20000),y = rep(NA,20000))
```

or restructure your code to avoid this sort of incremental addition of rows. As discussed at the link I cite, the reason for the slowness is that each time you add a row, R needs to find a new contiguous block of memory to fit the data frame in. Lots 'o copying.

Comment: so I reallocated the dataframe and started inserting 1row dataframes into it (df[j]<- newrow). It seems to be also getting slow as the number of insertions grow. Have you seen this before?

Comment: @Mark Yeah, like I said, this sort of thing is rather un-R-like. Modifying objects will still require a certain amount of copying of the entire object. Do you really want to copy the entire data frame each time you add a row? Probably not. Generate a list of each row using `lapply` and then stitch them together using `do.call(rbind,...)`. But beyond that, the solution requires more refactoring than I can help with given the information you've provided.

Comment: Kudos. Thanks a lot. I have thought a lot about using apply here but the problem has such a weird shape my brain is incapable of comprehending a proper functional form for it :) thanks for the help

Comment: I'm a little surprised that the `df[j,] <- newrow` is also slow, and particularly that it would get slower later in the run.  I can appreciate that it would require some dataframe copying, but it should be orders of magnitude faster than the second-circle-of-hell approach ...

Comment: @BenBolker Me too, but it's basically impossible to know what might be going on without more complete code.

Comment: @BenBolker I changed my code to use df[j,] <- newrow and the code is fast enough even after hundread of thousands of rows in the dataframe. The end results will be a dataframe populated with about 2 million rows in it.

Comment: see also another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472414/saving-the-outputs-of-a-loop-in-r-into-a-dataframe) that recommends to put the results into a list and rbind-ing them all at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I tried an example.  For what it's worth, it agrees with the user's assertion that inserting rows into the data frame is also really slow.  I don't quite understand what's going on, as I would have expected the allocation problem to trump the speed of copying. Can anyone either replicate this, or explain why the results below (rbind < appending < insertion) would be true in general, or explain why this is not a representative example (e.g. data frame too small)?

**edit**: the first time around I forgot to initialize the object in `hell2fun` to a data frame, so the code was doing matrix operations rather than data frame operations, which are *much* faster.  If I get a chance I'll extend the comparison to data frame vs. matrix.  The qualitative assertions in the first paragraph hold, though.

```
N <- 1000
set.seed(101)
r <- matrix(runif(2*N),ncol=2)

## second circle of hell
hell2fun <- function() {
    df <- as.data.frame(rbind(r[1,])) ## initialize
    for (i in 2:N) {
        df <- rbind(df,r[i,])
    }
}

insertfun <- function() {
    df <- data.frame(x=rep(NA,N),y=rep(NA,N))
    for (i in 1:N) {
        df[i,] <- r[i,]
    }
}

rsplit <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(r)))
rbindfun <-  function() {
    do.call(rbind,rsplit)
}

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(hell2fun(),insertfun(),rbindfun())

##          test replications elapsed relative user.self 
## 1  hell2fun()          100  32.439  484.164    31.778 
## 2 insertfun()          100  45.486  678.896    42.978 
## 3  rbindfun()          100   0.067    1.000     0.076
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `rsplit <- split(data.frame(r), seq_len(nrow(r)))` for a fairer comparison, and assign within the function. Then use `data.table::rbindlist` http://stackoverflow.com/a/12718498/1385941

Comment: will do when I get a chance (I don't understand the first sentence yet ... if I understand correctly, I don't think the matrix-splitting should be charged to the function -- I assumed that the rows would become available one by one within some sort of iterative procedure)

Comment: assign the result  `(df <- do.call(rbind, rsplit))` within the function (on reading, my commentwasunintelligible).