# Trying to add a column and a row in R via Linux Terminal

Tags: r

I am currently using R for work statics and whenever I want to add a column or a row I always go back to .csv file.

What command should i use to input the data via the terminal ? I use Linux OS.

Comment: Your screenshot and `java` tag were both irrelevant to your question - i've removed them.

Comment: You had a `java` **tag** on this question. I'm more than well aware what R is, as are most people around these parts. We just don't need a screenshot of your desktop to figure this question out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single, command-line addition rbind will do.

```
r rbind(Data, newrow)
```

Just keep in mind that for repeated application, rbind is [known to be slow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693956/how-can-i-prevent-rbind-from-geting-really-slow-as-dataframe-grows-larger)