# Create function to avoid url error in R for loop

Tags: r, http, web-scraping, http-status-codes

I am looping through a .csv filled with urls to scrape a website (authorizing scraping).

I was using a `trycatch` function to try to avoid breaks in my `for` loop.
But I noticed it stops for some urls (using `download.file`).

So I am now using a *« is this a valid url? »* function taken from this post:
[[Scrape with a loop and avoid 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39633333/scrape-with-a-loop-and-avoid-404-error][1])

```
url_works <- function(url){
tryCatch(
    identical(status_code(HEAD(url)),200L), 
    error = function(e){
        FALSE
    })
}
```

But even with this function, and looping only if outcome of the function is `TRUE`,  at some point my loop breaks on some urls and I get the following error:

```
> HTTP status was '500 Internal Server Error'
```

I would like to understand this error so that I add this case in the URL function to ignore in case of this url type comes out again.

Any thoughts ?
Thanks !

Comment: [httr](http://httr.r-lib.org/) has some ways of dealing with this, or [`purrr::possibly`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/safely.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tryCatch` syntax is wrong, I also changed the error message to print the error:

A generic `tryCatch` looks like:

```
tryCatch({
    operation-you-want-to-try
   }, error = function(e) do-this-on-error
)
```

So for your code:

```
url_works <- function(url){
    tryCatch({
        s1 <- status_code(HEAD(url))
        }, error = function(e) print(paste0(url, " ", as.character(e)))
    )
    identical(s1, 200L)
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it still gives the same error and stops.

Comment: Please provide an example of what a `url` is so we can test.

Comment: I actually resolved the solution thanks to your first comment ! About the trycatch. I edited with your version and it seems that now the download.file does not stop the for loop even we there is an error. For the url_works function, I am really intrigued by the fact that the status code will always be 200 when the url is working, do we know the reason for that ? I wiil mark your response as correct !

Comment: `HTTP` has a standard set of response codes based on the server's response to the client request, the 200 code is the standard response for a successful request: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes