# if link fails try again or skip to next link

Tags: r

i am facing trouble need help.

i have list of links (about 9000 links) which i am running in loop and doing some process on each one

links look like this :-

link1
link2
link3
link4
.....
link9000

but i am facing trouble as sometimes link 2nd gets failed (timeout) and sometime link2nd works and 400 or any random link fails as timeout . is there any way i can try failed link again n again ? i have added :-

`status_c <- httr::GET(Links, config = httr::config(connecttimeout = 150))`
but still i get timeout . please help me! or any suggestion regarding it? final_links_bind = have all list of links
some sample links:-

```
https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146711
https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146703
https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146789

  for(i in 1:nrow(final_links_bind)) {
Links <- final_links_bind[i,]
BP_ID <- final_bp_bind[i,]
#print(Links)
status_c <- GET(Links,timeout(120))
status <- status_code(status_c)
if(status == "200"){
  url_parse<- read_html(Links)
  col_name<- url_parse %>%
    html_nodes("tr") %>%
    html_text()
  col_name <- stringr::str_remove_all(col_name, "\\\t|\\\n|\\\r")
  pattern_col_no <- grep("využití", col_name)
  col_name <- as.data.frame(col_name)
  method_selected <- col_name[pattern_col_no,]
  WRITE_CSV_DATA <- rbind(WRITE_CSV_DATA, data.frame(BP_ID = c(BP_ID), method_selected = c(method_selected), Links = c(Links)))
  #METHOD_OF_USE <- rbind(method_selected,METHOD_OF_USE)
  print(WRITE_CSV_DATA)
  
}else{
  print("LINK NOT WORKING")
  no_Links <- sorted_link[i,]
  not_working_link <- rbind(not_working_link,no_Links)
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide some of the links and more of your code so we can test?

Comment: edited ! with code

Comment: what kind of info would you like to extract from the sites?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52371296/create-function-to-avoid-url-error-in-r-for-loop) is relevant.  Also, `rbind`ing inside your loop is inefficient.  better, write a function that processes a single element of `final_links_bind`, call it using `lapply` and *then* bind the results together...

Comment: @Tom one table which looks like this :- Zpusob využití:rodinný dum

Comment: i was rbinding inside loop because i was getting timeout error after timeout i will atleast have some data to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear how you want the final output, but here is how to scrape and skip links that are not working

```
library(rvest)
library(httr2)
library(tidyverse)
```

Given this data frame of links, notice the third one is not working:

```
df <- tibble(
  links = c(
    "https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146711",
    "https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146703",
    "https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/9999999",
    "https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146789"
  )
)

# A tibble: 4 × 1
  links                                                
  <chr>                                                
1 https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146711
2 https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146703
3 https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/9999999
4 https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146789
```

Create a function to scrape the table, specifically the third row:

```
get_info <- function(link) {
  cat("Scraping", link, "\n")
  link %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_table() %>%
    pluck(2) %>%
    slice(3) %>%
    pull(2) 
}
```

And `mutate()` a new column with the info, NA if the link is not working. If the link is not working `possibly()` will throw NA (`NA_character_`) back instead of stopping the code.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    info = map_chr(links, possibly(get_info, otherwise = NA_character_))
  )

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  links                                                 info       
  <chr>                                                 <chr>      
1 https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146711 rodinný dům
2 https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146703 rodinný dům
3 https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/9999999 NA         
4 https://vdp.cuzk.cz/vdp/ruian/stavebniobjekty/2146789 rodinný dům
```

Comment: thank you, it does not give what i want . hey it solves my problem

Comment: @walle_eva What do you want then? Kindly edit your question to display the expected output/results so I can adjust the code :)