# Saving the outputs of a loop in R (into a dataframe)

Tags: r, dataframe, function, loops

I have a loop that iterates over a list of formulas (which include different variables of my input data) and runs the adonis function over my data.

This loop outputs a data frame that contains the R squared and p-values for each variable in the formula as calculated by adonis in a PERMANOVA analysis.

How do I save the dataframe generated from each iteration (i.e for each formula?)

Example data:

```
sampleID <- c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5")
 variables <- c("stage", "type", "treatment")
 n <- length(variables)
 id <- unlist(lapply(1:n, function(i)combn(1:n,i,simplify=FALSE)),recursive=FALSE)
 formulas <- sapply(id,function(i) paste("data~",paste(variables[i],collapse="+")))
    
stage <- c(1,2,2,3,3)
type <- c("cancer", "dysplasia", "dysplasia", "cancer", "cancer")
treatment <- c("yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no")
metadata <- data.frame(cbind(sampleID, stage, type, treatment))
data <- data.frame(sampleID, X = sample(1:5), Y = sample(1:5), Z = sample(1:5), A = sample(1:5))
data <- data.matrix(data)
```

This is the loop:

```
library(vegan)    
adonis_test <- for (i in 1:length(formulas)){
  z =  adonis(as.formula(formulas[i]) , data=metadata)
  return(data.frame(name = rownames(z$aov.tab), R2 = z$aov.tab$R2, 'Pr(>F)' = z$aov.tab$'Pr(>F)')[1,])}
```

Comment: you have not included the code for `adonis` and hence it is not reproducible

Comment: Why not create an empty `dataframe` and `rbind` to it after each iteration?

Comment: @JasonMathews, that's a bad idea, imo. Iteratively adding rows to a `data.frame` works fine for ones and twos, but doing it repeatedly scales poorly (see *"Chapter 2: Growing Objects"* in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

1. `for` loops return nothing.
2. Iteratively adding rows to a `data.frame` works for one or two or so, but in general it scales very poorly; see *"Chapter 2: Growing Objects"* in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) for some fun/light reading. Long-story-short: each row added requires that all rows be copied in memory into a new object. This means when you have 500 rows, adding 1 row results in those 500 rows needing to be copied (now 1000 rows in memory) to a new object. This is fast-enough for small frames, but its asymptotic growth is terrible.

In general, it's best to put the results into a `list` (which does not involve copying all data every time you append one thing to it), and then `rbind`-ing them all at once.

Generally, I recommend using `lapply` for this, perhaps something like

```r
res <- lapply(seq_along(formulas), function(i) {
  z =  adonis(as.formula(formulas[i]) , data=metadata)
  data.frame(
    name = rownames(z$aov.tab), R2 = z$aov.tab$R2,
    'Pr(>F)' = z$aov.tab$'Pr(>F)'
  )[1,]
})
resDF <- do.call(rbind, res)
```

If you really prefer the `for` loop (and there *are* some advantages), then

```r
res <- list()
for (i in seq_along(formulas)) {
  z =  adonis(as.formula(formulas[i]) , data=metadata)
  res[[i]] <- data.frame(
    name = rownames(z$aov.tab), R2 = z$aov.tab$R2,
    'Pr(>F)' = z$aov.tab$'Pr(>F)'
  )[1,]
}
resDF <- do.call(rbind, res)
```

One advantage to a `for` loop here in place of `lapply`: if there is the possibility of a failure with one or more of the iterations, the `lapply` will fail and return nothing, whereas the `for` loop implementation will have all preceding successfully-completed models stored in `res`. Granted, if you want to *continue*, you need to manually modify the `for` loop indexing to continue where you left off (optionally skipping the problem).

However ... if you expect that to happen, then `tryCatch` is your friend, allowing even the `lapply` implementation to not lose-all-progress with one failure. Doing that well takes a bit more than this Q&A topic, but realize that there are methods.

---

Side note: being a little more defensive in programming, use `seq_along(formulas)` (or `seq_len(length(formulas))`) instead of `1:length(.)`. Why? In an automated fashion, if `formulas` is ever empty, then `length(.)` will be 0, and `1:0` returns a vector of length 2, as `c(1, 0)`. Since the intent of the `for` loop is to only execute as needed, this is a logical-flow error and will almost certainly `Error:` (or at least corrupt or unnecessarily process data). On the other hand, `seq_along(formulas)` and `seq_len(length(.))` resolve to `seq_len(0)` which ... returns `integer(0)`, and the `for` loop will not iterate at all.