# How can I simplify this code (r) in which I am using information from an original data set to create a new dataset?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have a data set that I am trying to use to generate a different data set in R. The dataset has many columns; but the three relevant columns for generating the new data set are "Reach", "Results", and "DV". Reach and results are numeric. DV is binary with 0s and 1s. In the original dataset, all rows have DV = 0.

For each row of the original data set, I am attempting to take one variable "Reach" and replicate that row "reach" number of times.
Then for this new set of rows, I want to change DV from 0 to 1 for "results" number (from the original row) of the new rows.

For example, in row 33 of the original data set: Reach = 1004, Results = 45, DV = 0. The new data set should have row 33 replicated 1004 times, for 45 of those new rows DV should be changed from 0 to 1.

The code I wrote for the task works... but it is taking 10+ hours to run because the file is so large. Any ideas for how to simplify this code so it can process more quickly

```
empty_new.video <- new.video[FALSE,]
for(i in 1:nrow(new.video)){
  n.times <- new.video[i,'Reach'] #determine number of times to repeat rows
  if (n.times > 0){
    for (j in 1:n.times){
      empty_new.video[nrow(empty_new.video) + 1 , ] <- new.video[i,]
    }
  }
  dv.times <- new.video[i,'Results'] #creating dependent variable 
  if (dv.times>0){
    for (k in 1:dv.times){
      empty_new.video[nrow(empty_new.video) - n.times + k,'DV'] <- 1
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697700/how-to-speed-up-rbind. `rep` function may help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693956/how-can-i-prevent-rbind-from-geting-really-slow-as-dataframe-grows-larger/14694108#14694108

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko op doesn't even use rbind in the example, how could speeding up rbind help?

Comment: I meant to create a subset of required rows with rep, and then rbind it to final df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a loop to do everything at once, you could define a simple function that does this for one row and check the results

```
dd <- data.frame(Reach = c(5, 3), Results = c(4, 1), DV = c(0, 0))
#   Reach Results DV
# 1     5       4  0
# 2     3       1  0

f <- function(data) {
  nr <- data$Reach
  nd <- data$Results
  data <- data[rep_len(1L, nr), ]
  data$DV <- rep(0:1, c(nr - nd, nd))
  rownames(data) <- NULL
  data
}
f(dd[1, ])
```

Then loop for every row

```
res <- lapply(split(dd, rownames(dd)), f)
do.call('rbind', res)
#     Reach Results DV
# 1.1     5       4  0
# 1.2     5       4  1
# 1.3     5       4  1
# 1.4     5       4  1
# 1.5     5       4  1
# 2.1     3       1  0
# 2.2     3       1  0
# 2.3     3       1  1
```

But really all you are doing is creating a vector of row indices and 0/1 values for `DV`, you could do that with `rep`

```
ii <- rep(1:nrow(dd), dd$Reach)

jj <- c(t(cbind(dd$Reach - dd$Results, dd$Results)))
dv <- rep(rep(0:1, nrow(dd)), jj)

within(dd[ii, ], {
  DV <- dv
})
#     Reach Results DV
# 1       5       4  0
# 1.1     5       4  1
# 1.2     5       4  1
# 1.3     5       4  1
# 1.4     5       4  1
# 2       3       1  0
# 2.1     3       1  0
# 2.2     3       1  1
```

Comment: Thanks! I am getting a message that using nr in rep_len(1L, nr) is an invalid 'length.out' value. Any idea what's happening there? I've confirmed nr is an integer

Comment: is reach ever negative? is reach always greater than results?

Comment: reach is always greater than zero  and always greater than results

Comment: Got it to work!! thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Avoid growing objects in loop. Consider `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) to iterate through all original dataset's columns elementwise to build a list of data frames to eventually concatenate **once** at the end.

```r
build_rows <- function(reach, results) {
    # DATA FRAME TO REPLICATE REACH BY ITS LENGTH
    df <- data.frame(id = reach, reach = 1:reach, dv = 0)

    # RANDOMLY ASSIGN N ROWS TO 1 (N=RESULTS)  
    df$dv[sample(1:nrow(df), results),] = 1 

    # ASSIGN FIRST N ROWS TO 1 (N=RESULTS)
    df$dv[1:results,] = 1 

    return(df)
}

df_list <- Map(build_rows, original_data$Reach, original_data$Results)

final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```